# How Can I Set a subclass field in Protocol Buffer, from Java Code?

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I Have an Animal A Cat and Dog messages, but i don't know how to set cat's declawed, or dog's bones_buried field, if I create an object. 
I want to create a Cat, and create an animal object from it.

```
message Animal {
extensions 100 to max;
enum Type {
    Cat = 1;
    Dog = 2;
}
    required Type type = 1;
}


message Cat {
    extend Animal {
        required Cat animal = 100;
    }
    optional bool declawed = 1;
}
message Dog {
    extend Animal {
        required Dog animal = 101;
    }
    optional uint32 bones_buried = 1;
}
```

my Test Class:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal.Builder animal = Animal.newBuilder().setType(Animal.Type.Cat);
    Cat c = animal.getExtension(Cat.animal);        

    Cat cat = Cat.newBuilder().setDeclawed(true).build();

    // animal = cat! 
    Animal a = animal.build();      

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful!  Protobuf extensions are *not* subclasses.  They can sometimes be used as a substitute for inheritance, but they work very differently from inheritance.  For example, your `Animal` type can actually have *both* a `Cat` *and* a `Dog` extension at the same time.

Extensions actually behave like fields.  Each time you `extend Animal`, you are essentially adding new fields to the `Animal` message.  In other words, your proto is actually equivalent to this:

```
message Animal {
  enum Type {
    Cat = 1;
    Dog = 2;
  }
  required Type type = 1;
  optional Cat cat = 100;
  optional Dog dog = 101;
}

message Cat {
  optional bool declawed = 1;
}
message Dog {
  optional uint32 bones_buried = 1;
}
```

The only difference is that extensions can be declared outside of the message that they are extending.

In retrospect, I should have used a different word than "extend" to avoid confusion with inheritance.

Since extensions are just fields, they have accessors equivalent to field accessors.  Here's how your code should be written:

```
Animal animal = Animal.newBuilder()
    .setType(Animal.Type.Cat);
    .setExtension(Cat.animal,
        Cat.newBuilder().setDeclawed(true))
    .build();
```

By the way, in your example you declare your extensions `required`.  This is actually not allowed -- extensions can never be required, because extensions by their nature are inherently optional.  If required extensions were actually allowed, then your proto would actually be declaring that every `Animal` had to have *both* a `Cat` and a `Dog` extension.